# BIMSurfer Javascript does not showing model

Tags: javascript, 3d, ifc, bim

I have used **BIMServer** (https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMserver/releases) latest version with **tomcat 9** and it is running well. I have also downloaded **BIMSurfer** (https://github.com/opensourcebim/BIMsurfer) latest version and tried to render **IFC** file with demo HTML files (under apps/minimal.html) given in that example.

Previously it has some errors related to server path and username/password, I have resolved that and now it does not showing any error but it also not render 3D model (It just shows blank screen). It shows 3D model on BIMServer backend. For reference I am attaching screen shots.[Shows Blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NVfz.png) [On Admin it render 3D model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muFrh.png)

I appericiate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I have found answer after spend lot of time on debugging and R&D it was issue with BIMSurfer version. I have changed it to bimsurfer3-0.0.17 (https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMsurfer/releases/tag/bimsurfer3-0.0.17) and it is working now.

So finally I am running BIMServer and BIMSurfer with following versions and setting.

- > JAVA - 8 Oracle
- > Apache Tomcat/9.0.19
- > BIMServer - 1.5.125
- > BIMSurfer - 3-0.0.17